# Change (same) variables of multiple objects quickly

Tags: java, performance, graph, nodes

I have an implementation of depth-first search for a directed graph with same size edges. This search changes the state of the nodes in my graph. So if I want to do a new search all nodes have to be **reset to default**.

My implementation:

```
public void resetGraph() {      
    ListItem temp = nodes.getHead();
    while(temp != null){
        DiGraphNode node = temp.key;
        node.visitorState = VISITORS.NONE;      //Set all nodes their initial state 
        node.sumOfDistances = 0;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

=> This takes some time for a large graph

Is there a way to do this more time efficient ?
Maybe someting like:

```
DiGraphNode.someStaticMethod(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your structure stands at the moment there is little you can do - you must visit every node to reset it so you are stuck with an `O(n)` algorithm.

One possible solution that **may** improve performance a little would be to keep track of all of your `visitorState` and `sumOfDistances` fields in an array. You could then use a `int nodeID` (generated at node construction time perhaps) to access the state and sum. The benefit of this tweak would be to allow you to use [Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28long[],%20long%29) which **may** make use of cpu-specific block-set instructions.

You will not be able to change the order of the algorithm but you might find some speed-up this way.